# Index 4 out of bounds for length 3. For Union Array

Tags: java, arrays, foreach, stringindexoutofbounds

//Whenever I run the code, it keeps giving me the same error. I don't understand why. The union array function's loop also isn't looping completely, likely a problem with the string index out of bound.

//I've tried to change the original function isNumberInArray, but still doesn't work.

```
package HW;

public class HW_5 {


public static boolean isNumberInArray(int number_check, int array[]) {
    for (int value : array) {
        value -= 1;
        if (number_check == array[value]) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}


public static int highestlength(int array_1[]) {
    int max = array_1[0];
    for (int counter = 1; counter < array_1.length; counter++) {
        if (array_1[counter] > max) {
            max = array_1[counter];
        }
    }
    return max; 
}


public static int [] unionArrays(int [] array_1, int [] array_2) {
    int array_index_counter = 0;
    int highest_1 = highestlength(array_1);
    int highest_2 = highestlength(array_2);
    int[] union_array = new int[array_1.length + array_2.length];
    if (highest_1 > highest_2) {
    for (int value_1 : array_1) {
        if (isNumberInArray(value_1, array_1) && isNumberInArray(value_1, array_2)) {
            union_array[array_index_counter] = value_1;
            array_index_counter += 1;
        } else {
            for (int value_2 : array_2) {
                if (isNumberInArray(value_2, array_1) && isNumberInArray(value_2, array_2)) {
                    union_array[array_index_counter] = value_2;
                    array_index_counter += 1;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
    printArray(union_array);
    return union_array;
}



public static void printArray(int array[]) {
    for (int value : array) {
        System.out.print(value + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}


public static void main(String[] Args) {
    int list_1[] = {1, 2, 3};
    int list_2[] = {1, 3, 5};
    System.out.println(isNumberInArray(0, list_1));
    System.out.println(unionArrays(list_1, list_2));
}
}


I expected the output to be 1 2 3 5, but the actual output is 0 0 0 0.
```

Answer (score 1):

For a start the looping in `isNumberInArray` is strange, try

```
public static boolean isNumberInArray(int number_check, int array[]) {
    for (int value : array) {
        if (number_check == value) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Probably because of this your `if` statements in `unionArrays` are always `false`

Comment: Nothing really happened.  :(

Comment: Also you do `if (highest_1 > highest_2) {` but the arrays are the same size.  Oh I see it is just getting the max value.  Array2 has the max value, so this `if` statement will not be entered into

Comment: I got rid of that part. Now I'm getting, 1 3 0 0, better than before. Yay

Comment: You want to do two loops (not nested).  One for each array.  Try using a debugger and stepping through your code.  Also see [Rubber Ducking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging)

Comment: Since I'm new to overflow, it says it won't display in public, but it does take it into account.